# Enviar paquetes UDP usando Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, netbeans

Estoy intentando hacer una app en Android (soy bastante nuevo con Android) que envíe paquetes UDP desde un cliente, la app que estoy haciendo en Android, a un server en Python que está corriendo en mi localhost (127.0.0.1).
El caso es que tengo todo el código hecho y en Netbeans el código funciona perfectamente pero cuando lo paso a Android Studio no envía ningún paquete. He sniffeado la red loopback con el Wireshark y efectivamente no se envía nada. Por supuesto, he habilitado la opción de Internet en el Manifest.xml de la app: 
**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"**

A continuación adjunto algunas lineas de mi código donde se deberían enviar los paquetes:

```
public void sendPackets() throws IOException {
    DecimalFormat numberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.0000");
    double d;
    Instant ts2;
    DatagramPacket datagram;
    ByteBuffer msg;
    for (int i = 0; i < this.packets; i++) {
        ts2 = Instant.now();
        d = (double)  ts2.getEpochSecond()+ (double) ts2.getNano() / 1000_000_000;
        String[] ts = numberFormat.format(d).split(",");
        msg = ByteBuffer.allocate(this.size);
        msg.putInt(i);
        msg.putInt(Integer.parseInt(ts[0]));
        msg.put(ts[1].getBytes());
        msg.putInt(0);
        msg.putInt(0);
        byte[] msg_array = msg.array();
        datagram = new DatagramPacket(msg_array, msg_array.length, this.ip, this.port);
        this.socket.send(datagram);
        System.out.println("Packet " + i + " has been sent!");
    }
    System.out.println("All packets have been sent!");
}
```

Se envía a la ip 127.0.0.1 y al puerto donde se esta corriendo el servidor, por ejemplo el 1234. Si lo ejecuto desde el emulador de Android o desde un dispositivo real no se envía ni un solo paquete, sin embargo si lo envío desde Netbeans, recibo todo. No entiendo qué esta pasando. ¿Alguien me podría echar una mano?

Muchas gracias a todos por adelantado y felices fiestas!!

Comment: Captura el error de `this.socket.send` en un `try catch` de esa forma tendremos mas idea de que es lo que ocurre.

Comment: El problema parece ser que tiene que ver con la IP. Hasta ahora estaba ejecutando el servidor en localhost (127.0.0.1) pero para que haya conexión con el emulador tengo que poner la ip de mi ordenador 192.168.x.x . La verdad que no entiendo porque no puedo ejecutar el server en localhost.

Answer (score 1):

Si tu servidor esta corriendo en el localhost, los dos programas tienen que estar conectados en la misma red. Si ya estaban conectados en la misma red. Verifica que tu `AndroidManifest` tenga los permisos de internet

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Si quieres acceder a este servidor desde cualquier red entonces alojas el servidor direccion ip que te da https://whatismyipaddress.com/ en lugar del localhost

Tener en cuenta que si el ordenador que esta corriendo este servidor esta conectado a un router por wifi, tienes que abrir los puertos del router. Por ejemplo si tu servidor esta alojado en el puerto `1234` tienes que abrir estos puertos en la configuración del router.

Comment: Muchas gracias Noel por tu respuesta y tu ayuda. Me ha sido de gran ayuda y me has ayudado a solventar mi problema. Muy agradecido!